# why is bootstrap width limited to 940px only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a new MVC site using twitter bootstrap.
but I think it is not serving the desired purpose. I want to utilize maximum screen-width but at the same time also want to use span* and offset* classes. I think, 940px is too small considering nowadays the screens are having significant large widths. How can we overcome this limitation, or should I not use bootstrap at all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fluid grid system then:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the fluid grid system but still want a bigger grid, you can build a customized version of bootstrap [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html%5d) and experiment with varying column/gutter widths. The total width of the container will be `(@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@gridColumns - 1))`.